# ASP.NET view possible vulnerability exposing DB table names to user?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, security

I am currently learning ASP.NET MVC C# Code First.

Upon scaffolding the views or using Razor syntax to help generate forms, I notice that the code created sets the html form element names to the exact names of the db tables within the database. Furthermore, this exposes the database structure and entity relationships.

Example Razor Syntax in View

`@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Product.ProductType.Name)`

The Generated Html as follows

```
<input id="Product_ProductType_Name" 
    name="Product.ProductType.Name" 
    type="hidden" value="Fruits" />
```

Just from this little snippet of generated html, a user of the system would be able to tell that there are 2 tables and the name of a field as written in the db:

- Product
- ProductType
- Name (ProductType field)

Is there a way of hiding this e.g. putting in a hidden table prefix such as `asdf_` making the table names `asdf_Product` and `asdf_ProductType` respectively or is this not necessary?

Let's assume that this was a username / password field. A potential hacker would know exactly the names of the tables which it should try to attack.

Please advise if I have no reason to worry.

Comment: I would agree that this is reason to worry.  However, prefixes aren't going to fix the problem.  If a hacker knows they can get the table names straight from the code I'm sure they'll be able to quickly identify prefixes and adjust accordingly.  I'd say stay away from generated views and build them yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a view model for the view in question. This basically includes creating a new Model class, where you add only the items that are necessary and where you can change the names of the fields as necessary.

```
class FormViewModel
{
    string viewName;
    ...

    public FormViewModel(ProductType type)
    {
        viewName = type.Name;
        ...
    }
}
```

This can then be passed to the views in place of your EF model. When the model is returned to an Action, you can simply reverse the process:

```
Product.ProductType.Name = model.viewName;
```

This also helps to avoid passing "junk" data around to views - you're not passing the whole kitchen when all you need is a spoon.

Answer (score 2):

Knowing table names is not in itself a vulnerability. Your application should be resilient to attack even if the table names are known.

After all if it has some vulnerability that allows queries to be executed for known table names then the attacker could just use query `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` first and retrieve the table names.

Just make sure that you parameterise all queries and the account used by the site does not have unnecessary privileges

Answer (score 0):

Strange, showing the tablenames on the view? I prefer to use the models only to show data needed for the view. So you dont have to expose any structure. Just make a new layer for db-access, use the repository pattern and never make a call to your db from your controller. I would say its bad design. MVC is a view-pattern and a view with db-access is dangerous.

Make a new project for your db and use repository and unit of work pattern. Dont throw your viewmodels in the database, use them as data transfer objecs to validate the modelstate from the user input and keep the logic in other layers like businesslayer.

Seperation of concerns...
I use an extra layer for dataasscess (DAL) and a common area for my entities.

And by the way, i hope you use [RequireHttps] and an Antiforgerytoken in your forms and your controllers.